# Brunch asset filter

Tags: config, assets, brunch

I'd like to apply a filter instead of simply copying all files over from the asset folder. (such as do not include font files if we are running in production)

Is this possible?

(If it isn't possible, can anyone give any additional insights on how I might accomplish that?)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you will need to edit config's directive `conventions.assets`: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#conventions

```

```
config =
  conventions:
    assets: (path) ->
      (not /\.woff/.test path) and /assets(\/|\\)/.test path
```

```

Comment: What if I want to dump the assets in a lower directory than public?